PostgreSQL Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
During the installation of postgresql, a problem appears:
The database cluster initialization failed...
And therefore the PostgreSQL/16/data folder is empty.  When I tried to initialize this folder I got the following error:
initdb: error: program "postgres" was found by program "D:/PostgreSQL/16/bin/initdb.exe", but its version is different from initdb
I tried several times to completely delete the program and download it again to C:/Program Files/.  But nothing helped and then I decided to change the drive to D: but even this did not help.
In addition, the service of Postgres is not at all in services.msc
Help me please... Thanks in advance!
